# WebSphere 9.0 Jersey Sample Application

Tags: jersey, websphere

I am looking for sample RESTFull application, that can be deployed in Webpshere Application Server 9.x. Posting here with great hope after exhaustive search. Any help much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

There are many samples, here you have two, they are for WebSphere Liberty, but the main concepts and code is the same:

- [OpenLiberty /sample-restful-webservice](https://github.com/OpenLiberty/sample-restful-webservice)
- [Creating a RESTful web service](https://openliberty.io/guides/rest-intro.html)

There is no need to use Jersey, just use JAX-RS api provided by container.